# connecting two apps using socketIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets

I have implemented a user interface to do some wizard of oz testing. I have a user-side page (Page A), and a second page, the wizard page (Page B). They use the same data and page B receives some information from page A to load the correct data. When the user asks questions on page A, the question is sent to page B, and an answer should be sent back to page A. The problem is that Page A is open on device A and page B is open on Device B (both are on the same server).

I am trying to implement the communication between page A and page B using socketIO. I searched for hours and didn't find a complete example of connecting two apps using socketIO. They usually open the same app in multiple windows. That won't help me. My understanding so far is that I should create a server for each app, and then have the two servers communicate with each other. What I have so far doesn't work and no communication is happening. What I have is as follow:

for page A (index.html):
I added a index.js server file:

```
// Import packages
const express = require("express");
const socketIO = require("socket.io");
const path = require("path");

// Configuration
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
//const INDEX = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');
const INDEX = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');
console.log("INDEX", INDEX);
//const WIZARD = path.join(__dirname, 'wizard.html');

// Start server
const server = express()
  //.use((req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX), (req, res) => res.sendFile(WIZARD))
  .use((req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX))
 .listen(PORT, () => console.log("Listening on localhost:" + PORT));

// Initiatlize SocketIO
const io = socketIO(server);

var other_server = require("socket.io-client")('http://localhost:4000');

other_server.on("connect",function(){
    other_server.on('message',function(data){
        // We received a message from Server 2
        // We are going to forward/broadcast that message to the "Lobby" room
        io.to('lobby').emit('message',data);
    });
});


io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){
  // Display a connected message
  console.log("User-Client Connected!");

  // Lets force this connection into the lobby room.
  socket.join('lobby');

  // Some roster/user management logic to track them
  // This would be upto you to add :)
  
  // When we receive a message...
  socket.on("message",function(data){
      // We need to just forward this message to our other guy
      // We are literally just forwarding the whole data packet
      other_server.emit("message",data);
  });
  
  socket.on("disconnect",function(data){
      // We need to notify Server 2 that the client has disconnected
      other_server.emit("message","UD,"+socket.id);
      
      // Other logic you may or may not want
      // Your other disconnect code here
  });
});
```

For the same app, to the index.html I added the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      // Get WebSocket
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

      // Client
      socket.on('connect', function(){
          socket.emit("message","This is my message");
          
          socket.on('message',function(data){
              console.log("We got a message: ",data);
          });
      });

      // Join a channel
      var room = "test";
      socket.emit("join", room);
      let msg = "hello helloo helloooo from index.html";
      socket.emit("new_message", msg);

      socket.on("new_message", function (msg) {
        console.log("sending a message through server from index.html", msg);
      });
     
    </script>
```

For the second app, wizard.html I added a server file, index.js:

```
// Import packages
const express = require("express");
const socketIO = require("socket.io");
const path = require("path");

// Configuration
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
//const INDEX = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');
const INDEX = path.join(__dirname, 'wizard.html');
console.log("INDEX", INDEX);
//const WIZARD = path.join(__dirname, 'wizard.html');

// Start server
const server = express()
  //.use((req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX), (req, res) => res.sendFile(WIZARD))
  .use((req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX))
 .listen(PORT, () => console.log("Listening on localhost:" + PORT));


// Server 2
const io = socketIO(server);

io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){
    // Display a connected message
    console.log("Server-Client Connected!");
    
    // When we receive a message...
    socket.on("message",function(data){
        // We got a message. I don't know, what we should do with this
    });
});
```

and to the wizard.html, I added the script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Get WebSocket
  //var socket = io();
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');

  // Join a channel
  var room = "test";
  socket.emit("join", room);
  let msg = "hello helloo helloooo from wizard";
  socket.emit("new_message", msg);

  socket.on("new_message", function (msg) {
    console.log("sending message through server from wizard", msg);
  });
  /*
  */
</script>
```

I also added `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`  to both apps, index.html, and wizard.html.

In wizard.html I get this error:
`POST http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OAp7bZr 400 (Bad Request)`

and in index.html I get this error:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OAp7k5w' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:`

If you can help me figure out what I am missing or if you know of any complete working example similar to what I am trying to accomplish, I would very much appreciate it if you let me know.

It would be even more helpful if someone could use the code and scenario I provided here and write a minimum working example in which the two apps, a.html, and b.html, can communicate through socketIO.

Comment: each client doesnt need its own server, multiple clients connect to 1 server. socket io has a good [get started](https://socket.io/get-started/chat) section

Comment: I am not familiar with `socket.io`. Have you tried the `ws` WebSocket library? It is straight forward to use. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws

Comment: @about14sheep, you mean I can have one index.js, and then two separate .html files each act as a client for that one server? In the example you linked, in the index.js the rout handler only knows index.html as the app. How do I add my wizard.html as the second client/app?

Comment: i think you need to read more into the basics behind web development. You will serve the same "page(index.html)" to each person(client). you could say you only need two files here, frontend(the html file) and backend(the index.js server file).